# Criteria for neighbors when calculating 2D lindemann parameter

Tags: geometry

I am trying to compute 2D lindemann parameter to quantify melting in colloidal crystals from particle coordinates obtained in 2D.

The equation I have come across for computing 2D lindemann parameter is as follows

$$L = \frac{\left\langle \left( \Delta u_{i}\left( t \right) -\Delta u_{j}\left( t \right) \right)^{2} \right\rangle}{2a^{2}} $$

where $$\Delta u\left( t \right) = u\left( t \right)-u\left( 0 \right)$$

*i* and *j* are the nearest neighbors, and *a* is the interparticle distance.

Now i am confused as what particles are considered neighbors in the system, is there a fixed cut-off distance that we consider or we take into account the whole system.

Please, if someone could shed some light on this

(DOI : https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.82.2721)

Comment: I think this is actually a physics question. However, if this is a crystal, and a is the "inter particle distance", it seems to me that nearest neighbours refers to all particles at distance a.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you start with particles arranged on a square lattice with side $a$. Then each particle has 4 neighbors. You can think of up, down, left, and right. Notice that you need to consider only two of them. For particle 1, if you look at the distance to the left to particle 2, it's the same as the distance from particle 2 to particle 1, looking at the right.

Let's label the particles by two indices, one the column number and one the row, and say you have $N$ particles in a row or in a column. Then what you need to compute is:
$$\frac1{2(N-1)^2}\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}\left[(\Delta u_{i,j}-\Delta u_{i+1,j})^2+(\Delta u_{i,j}-\Delta u_{i,j+1})^2\right]$$